# It's invisible to the naked eye... I hid it in this riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> We are *all* born with it, and we still have it.
>
> I hid it in this riddle **right above**, literally...
>
> It's invisible to the naked eye. What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could be

> [**DNA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA)

We are all born with it, and we still have it.

> We all have **DNA**

I hid it in this riddle **right above**, literally...

> Above the bold is reversed **DNA** as "**and**"

It's invisible to the naked eye. What is it?

> You'll need a powerful microscope to see **DNA**

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer must be

> Space

We are all born with it, and we still have it.

> Space can be defined as the volume in which a thing exists. For example, if I talk about "my space", I am referring to the physical volume in which I exist (plus probably extra). Everybody is born with this and continues to have it.

I hid it in this riddle right above, literally...

> We notice the literal space between the first and second line.

It's invisible to the naked eye.

> Normally we think of space as an emptiness which separates things and this would be invisible to the naked eye.

Comment: Sorry, but no. It would make the middle line of the riddle a bit arbitrary. Also, one could argue "But I currently don't have it!"; the actual answer would make it correct with no exceptions.